# Ubuntu 19.10, 20.04, DNS resolving to localhost - why?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

This one has been perplexing me. Fresh installs of ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 - the dns server defined always seems to point to localhost. I've tried hardcoding the dns server in network setting in gui.

I'm trying to have it point to my router which is running add blocking - but somewhere it is being forced to localhost - and driving me nutz.  The client is set up to use dns from dhcp.

What am I missing.  Thanks.

"Dig command"
; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)

"resolv.conf"
nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: Perfectly normal. That's the address for the local DNS cache (stub resolver). See `systemd-resolve --status` for what your DNS servers really are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I figured out what was going on.  After looking at some wireshark traces I figured out Firefox by default is set to use DNS over TLS and was using cloudflare as default provider.  This was bypassing my router dns with adblocks.  Once unchecked - no more ads.

Comment: Ah yes, the newest Firefox has that "DNS over TLS" option, and it's checked as enabled.